# Is it possible to receive events from Azure Event Hubs using REST API?

Tags: azure-eventhub

Is it possible to receive events from Azure Event Hubs using REST API?
I have found only send event API in the Azure documentation.
How to GET events?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

REST is not supported on the Event Hubs consumer side. Consumers must use one of these two protocols:

1. AMQP
2. Kafka

Please check this sample on sending and receiving events: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/get-started-dotnet-standard-send-v2